# Verify if GridView cell values are same on 3 column

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I validate 3 column cell values are same on the grid view. My code some how not working.O have 4 rows and 3 columns gridview. third column has all the different values... In this case my button1 has to be false. but it comes true

**code**

```
var isSame = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(x => Convert.ToString(x.Cells[2].Value))
            .Distinct().Count() == 1;

if (!isSame)
{
    button1.Enabled = true;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Not working? In what way?

Comment: O have 4 rows and 3 columns gridview. third column has all the different values... In this case my button1 has to be false. but it comes true

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, it is simpler in my mind.

```
        var x = (from x in GridView1.Rows
                 select x[2]).Distinct().ToList();

        if (x.Count == 1)
        { 
            //they are all the same
        }
```